# Application icon appearing in the corner of window

Tags: gnome, window, titlebar

I was trying to use Elementary interface in my Ubuntu. I also installed `elementary-tweaks`. I removed everything but I don't know if happened after removed.

Here goes what is happening, I didn't explain well.

[image: Printscreen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the small application icon next to the close button from the title-bar, you can do that by changing your window button-layout. Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

Alternatively, you can have the app-menu in the top bar instead. You may use *(GNOME) Tweaks*. First install it (if it is not installed) by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then launch Tweaks, go to "*Top Bar*" section and toggle **on** the "Application Menu" option.

[image]

Comment: The command line didn't work, but gnome-tweaks did! Thats nice, bro, thanks!

Comment: Just note: For some reason on my Ubuntu 18.04 the meaning of the TweakTool Application Menu's switch is inverted.

Comment: @pa4080 Are you sure? Just to clarify: In GNOME Tweaks, Application Menu ON = Application Menu in the *GNOME top bar* (not in the window title bar); Application Menu OFF = Application Menu in the *window title bar*. Is it the opposite for you?

Comment: Hi, @pomsky, thank you for the clarification! Actually I'm using "Dash to panel" extension and, for a while, I completely forgot about the Gnome's *top bar* appearance conception :) BTW, I'm looking for a extension that can put the Application Menu in the left of the window title bar, while minimize,maximize,close are positioned on the right side - if you have idea about such extension I would post a separate question.

Comment: Here it is: https://askubuntu.com/q/1190995/566421