# How do I move "Application menu" within the widows title bar on the left side while "minimize, maximize, close" buttons are placed on the right side?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, desktop-environments, window-buttons, gnome-tweaks

I'm looking for a way to move the application menu in the window's title bar on the left side as it is illustrated on the next image.

[image]

Optionally, I will be happy if there is some way to force such application menu to appear for non-GTK windows as Firefox, Chromium, GIMP, etc.

Comment: The second part is, I think, not achievable (easily) and  not very useful to begin with. The non-GTK applications you mentioned don't use the application-menu option at all. It only provides the default "Quit" option for those apps, nothing else.

Comment: @pomsky: I mean the title bars of these windows looks incomplete, so just an application icon in that place will be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the preferred ordering of window control buttons by running the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout appmenu:minimize,maximize,close
```

The `:` works as a "*separator*". You can put any button to the left or right of the `:` to make it appear on the left or right of the title-bar.

---

In order to place *something* in the left corner of the window title bar for all GTK and non GTK windows, you can modify the above command in this way ([reference](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Metacity)):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout menu:appmenu,minimize,maximize,close
```

Here is how the final result looks like for GTK and non GTK windows:

[image]

[image]